# PJSIP GreenJ without Qt?

Tags: javascript, sip, voip, pjsip

I want to write a javascript application which works with PJSIP in order to create sip calls to IP phone.
The project example  is [GreenJ](http://www.loremipsum.at/produkte/greenj/library/#en)
However the sample forces me to work with [Qt](http://qt-project.org/downloads) as a test telephone on the other side.
I don't want Qt to be the telephone on the other side, but my IP Phone to be.
Trying to remove "qt_handler" caused a compilation error in "phone-lib.js" file.
Can anyone help me with that or **give a simple hello world JavaScript example to use PJSIP**?
Thanks !

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use pjsip?

Comment: @DvideBy0 Why not? Its open source and is used by a lot of companies, is it not? Do you offer something more suitable instead? Thanks

Comment: I am not 100% sure of what your needs are in the end but there are things out there like phono (http://phono.com/) from Voxeo. This allows you to make sip calls to any endpoint rather easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should try this: https://github.com/hanshuebner/node-pjsip

You can not use pjsip directly from web browser.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it seems like a good start. What actually we did was to write our own C++ COM wrapper and loaded it from the browser in order to connect pjsip.

Comment: I want to do the same thing. I have been breaking my head for last 3 days. Can you please give some pointers? Such as an example of loading a C++ COM wrapper from the browser. Much Appreciated.